# Parquet column issue while loading data to SQL Server using spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, hive, parquet

I am facing the following issue while migrating the data from hive to SQL Server using spark job with query given through JSON file.

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Parquet column cannot be converted in file.
Column: [abc], Expected: string, Found: INT32
```

Now from what I understand is the parquet file contains different column structure than the Hive view. I am able to retrieve data using tools like Teradata, etc. While loading to different server causes the issue.

Can anyone help me understand the problem and give a workaround for the same?

Edit:
spark version 2.4.4.2
Scala version 2.11.12
Hive 2.3.6
SQL Server 2016

Comment: Can you try to view the data in Spark after extracting from Hive(before loading data into SQL server), with this we can say there is some issue with SQL server table datatype,  also check your target table column 'abc' datatype

Comment: Also, please add Spark, Hive and SQL server version details, so that we can understand better if any version incompatibility issue.

Comment: I am am able to read into DataFrame using spark.sql() ; while reading doesn't throw the error , displaying using df.show() does. Target SQL table column datatype is not an issue  and I am using varchar(250). It's the some Parquet file that has column 'abc' datatype different from that present in hive table structure

Comment: Oh. Ok. you might need to figure out the parquet file which is holding this column 'abc'

Comment: I have updated the version details to my original post. I do have the partition that's causing the issue. But I was wondering if there was a way without fixing the source parquet files. Like some cast or conversion that could be used.